# Appeal tag wiki rejection? Plagiarized - nothing?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-wiki, appeal

AS: this question seems to mix too many ideas into one soup. Would try to separate the concerns. So the question of ethics and self-esteem i offloaded to [Appeal tag wiki rejection? Plagiarized - nothing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212131)

Is there a standard way to appeal rejections, when they are made for bogus reasons ?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3602994

Matt Ball is entitled for his opinion (though i think that informative but informal description is anyway betetr than NULL). How it is said about questions - "enhance rather than close".

But two other decisions - This edit plagiarizes content from an external source without proper attribution - are nothing but insult that there seems no SO way to refute.

BTW, why at all this "plagiarism" insult is even possible to put without providing the source that allegedly was plagiarized?

---

It is interesting that some say like "the wiki page does not repeat the term" but the term is told in the excerpt that is always rendered together with main text. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/epsilon/info

Seems like separate review processes just make wiki need to copy-paste te excerpt once and again

Comment: You must admit, however, that the tag wiki you proposed _was_ unhelpful and kinda stupid. It makes a great blog post that's fun to read, but it doesn't really belong as a tag wiki. It doesn't even _mention_ epsilon

Comment: Well, "enhance rather than close". The wiki lists the typical errors and describes why they happen - doesn't that have value. And anyway pretending plagiarizing when there clearly was none is not a decent approach. If anything, it is bad because it disables other reviewers to make the assessment of the text itself due to made up excuse.

Comment: The standard way to appeal that is to suggest it again, but I wouldn’t.

Comment: Without clicking through to wikipedia your edit leaves me with no idea what "epsilon" means, so even if it's not plagiarism, it's certainly rejection-worthy.

Comment: @SpecialSnowflake that is not appeal - appeal means at least adding information (backing my opinion why the decision was wrong) and at best asking the reviewers to back their claims. Both options are not present when re-submitting.

Comment: Put it in the summary. If you feel it needs more discussion, ask on Meta. Well, we’re on Meta now, and here’s your appeal. :)

Comment: @OGHaza actually no one views the wiki without exerpt! there tag page has both of them. Read the full page and there it is: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/epsilon/info

Comment: Ah my bad, never viewed a tag-wiki edit before, assumed it was blank to begin with.

Comment: @OGHaza Well, it was blank before i filled both the excerpt and the body

Comment: @OGHaza, Arioch 'The: Actually, the `/info` page shows the excerpt by default only if full wiki has no content. For tags that do have a proper wiki, the excerpt is only shown if you explicitly click the "show excerpt" button. The full wiki is supposed to be an expanded version of the excerpt, not an appendix to it.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen okay, point taken. I also start a separate narrowly-aimed topic about insults. This topic is really "one size fits all" kind of mess.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a standard way to appeal rejections, when they are made for bogus reasons ?

That's built into the review system.  Three reviewers in a row that your edit was poor.  That means it was probably poor.  After reading it myself, I agree that it was poor.  The system worked correctly.  In the handful of cases where the editor still disagrees, he or she can appeal to meta, as you are now.  I suggest being more open to feedback in the event you choose to continue participating on StackExchange.

Comment: You see, there was almost no feedback. One blanket vague "you're doing it wrong" and two blatant lies.

Comment: @Arioch'The can you please explain which tag review guideline it follows?